# Discrepencies on disk sector size

Tags: linux, hard-drive

When asking using smartctl, I got the answer:

> Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical

When asking using fdisk, I got the answer:

> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

When asking using blockdev, I got the answer:

```
> RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device rw   256  
> 512  4096          0   1000204886016   /dev/sdc
```

Why are there differences? What are the consequences of this? What do I have to do?

Comment: I read the question as "why does physical sector size equal 4096 according to one tool but 512 according to another tool?" Still it can be interpreted as "what differs logical from physical?" The latter qualifies the question to be duplicate for sure. If you mean the former then please [edit] the question an clearly note this. In my opinion it wouldn't be a duplicate of the linked question in this case. After being edited, the question will undergo voting procedure to be reopened.

Comment: Mokubai is right, my question is duplicate with the mentioned one. Nevertheless, there is no response which explain why the discrepancy occurs. The mentioned utilities use different algorithms and therefore the result is different. But which one is the right one ? The other pieces of software working on the disk use probably different algorithms too. What are the consequences ?

Comment: "there is no response which explain why the discrepancy occurs" -- That's my point. The other question is about differences between various disks or different settings of a particular disk (if the disk allows this); which implicitly assumes that if a certain disk is there with such-and-such setup then every tool will report the same. If you're asking why the mentioned utilities yield different results *for one and the same disk at the same time* then your question is not a duplicate, because this topic is not covered there at all.